# JPA join different type columns

Tags: jpa

I'm Using EclipseLink (JPA 2.1).

I have an entity with a joined column to another antity.
My problem is that this joined column is with different types, in one entity it's String and in the other it's Short.

Is it possible to join them so that when I have a string value I will get null inside the second entity, and when the value is a number I will get the second entity?

This is my code:

first entity contains:

```
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Size(min = 1, max = 100)
@Column(name = "DRC3VALUE")
private String fieldValue;

@JoinColumn(nullable = true , name = "DRC3VALUE", referencedColumnName = "M12VAL", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(optional = false)    
private Table02 table02;
```

second entity contains:

```
@Id
@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull
@Column(name = "M12VAL")    
private Short tableValue;

@Basic(optional = false)
@NotNull    
@Column(name = "M12TXT")
private String tableText;
```

I want `table02` to be null if `fieldValue` is with a string value, and when it's a number I want it to be joined with `tableValue`.

Is this possible??

Thank's In Advance.